# Recognizing an erasable EPROM from a non-erasable one

Tags: programmer, eprom

I'm a Software Engineer looking at some datasheets for electronic components, and I've come across an inconsistency that I can't make sense of.

I'm looking at PROMs, specifically EPROMs, my thought being that if something goes wrong, we can remove the EPROM from the socket, reprogram it, and fix any problems. What I find confusing is that some PROMs are labeled as One Time Programmable EPROMs. To me this looks to be a contradiction. If an EPROM can only be programmed once, then what is the difference between a PROM and an EPROM? Would not a OTP EPROM be the same as a PROM?

One of the datasheets of interest was for an AT27LV020A. The chip package does not have a UV window for erasing. From the Datasheet

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0549.pdf

> The Atmel AT27LV020A is a high-performance, low-power, low-voltage,
> 2,097,152-bit,  one-time programmable, read-only memory (OTP
> **EPROM**) organized as 256K by 8 bits. It  requires only one supply in the range of 3.0 to 3.6V in normal read mode operation, making  it
> ideal for fast, portable systems using battery power. The Atmel
> innovative design techniques provide fast speeds that rival 5V parts,
> while keeping the low power consumption of a 3V supply. At VCC =
> 3.0V, any byte can be accessed in  less than 120ns. With a typical power dissipation of only 18mW at 5MHz and VCC = 3.3V,  the AT27LV020A
> consumes less than one-fifth the power of a standard, 5V **EPROM**.
> Standby mode supply current is typically less than 1µA at 3.3V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UV-erasable EPROMs required an expensive ceramic package with a quartz window so the EPROM chip could be exposed to ultra-violet light for erasure.

The same chips were also available in much cheaper plastic packages without the quartz window so they could not be erased - those were called "One-time programmable".

The idea was that you could develop your program using the erasable version, then use the OTP version for production. As the same chip was used in both packages, there was no concern of different chips behaving differently or requiring different programming procedures.

The electrically-erasable EEPROMs won't have erasable and OTP versions.

Answer (score 4):

Traditional PROMs are built completely different from EPROMs. A traditional PROM is built with a fuse structure, consisting of an array of wire links. High current is passed through these fuses which are physically destroyed to program them. (A variant was the anti-fuse, where a insulating layer breaks down and the wire welds across) These are physically irreversible processes.

Due to several reasons, including demand for erasable components, and issues with fuses on modern semiconductor fabrication processes, traditional PROMs have virtually disappeared, replaced by EEPROMs and Flash memory. Both of these store electrons in a floating gate MOSFET structure.

To satisfy the need for a one-time programmable part, typically for security or tamper-resistant type applications, they make these OTP EPROMs. They are exactly the same as an EEPROM, but the high-voltage erase circuitry has been disabled. This may be done intentionally, but also arises from binning, where the erase circuitry has been found to be defective, so the part is sold as OTP, for e.g. cheap kid's toys which will never receive a firmware update.

One important difference is that while a fuse-based PROM will last essentially forever, the charge can leak from OTP EPROMs, in the same manner as EEPROMs and Flash, leading to a limited data storage lifetime, particularly at elevated temperatures. The last hold out of fuse-based devices was space applications, where radiation can disturb the stored charge.

Comment: Long ago, I used OneTime Programmable (OTP) EPROMS that were really UV-erasable EPROMS in windowless plastic packages.  I don't recall versions of Electrically-eraseable EPROMs being sold as OTP.

Comment: @PeterBennett OP's linked Atmel part is such an example. Another example is [SpecTek OTP NAND](https://www.spectek.com/pdfs/SP_TN-00-01.pdf), basically defective Micron parts.

Comment: How do you test if the erase circuitry is faulty? Wouldn't the test sequence be something like this; 1) program values 2) read memory and compare with what was written 3) erase and check that it's erased. But if that is faulty you're left with a device programmed with the test data.

Comment: @DDuck In the SpecTek NAND datasheet I linked, it explains the defect is the wrong or unrelated blocks get erased. I suspect another failure mode could be it doesn't erase under normal conditions, you can erase under elevated temperatures or if you erase multiple times. I think the other option is when they test the die before packaging, you can UV still erase traditional Flash, obviously not an option for 3D Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing windowless EPROMs has been a topic of interest since the parts came out.
Yes, the same die is used in the OTP version as in the EPROM part, so you could erase the OTP part of you could get to the die.
That said, it IS possible to effect the data read from the parts using high intensity visible light. Try reading an OTP part, verify it to be sure it's correct, then verify it again while under a desk lamp or bright LED flashlight. It will error.  Same thing can happen with a plastic packaged microprocessor. Just a very bright light on the plastic package can crash it.  I haven't tried leaving an OTP under the light for very long, so it MAY erase. Interesting experiment.
Note, the current draw under the light can go up over a mA or two. Painting the package with a silver or yellow Sharpie can mitigate these effects.